# Автоматическое добавление данных

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, php

Здравствуйте.

На моем сайте есть возможность изменять данные в бд с использованием ajax. Есть различные select и button, то есть нужно выбрать значение, а потом нажать кнопку и данные изменятся.

Задача вот в чем: теперь нужно избавится от кнопки, чтобы данные добавлять автоматически при изменении select. На половину этих select я повесил событие onchange, и все хорошо работает, но на половине моих select установлен скриптовый календарь, и, как известно, если на select есть скрипт, то Onchange не работает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем можно данное событие заменить, чтобы работало так же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо таймером обновляете (создаете таймер и он обновляет).

Либо, я так понял, ваш скрипт календарика изменяет строку select, тогда при изменении вызывайте необходимую функцию (модифицируйте ваш скриптик).